# Save order of dynamically created jQuery Connected Sortable Lists

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

What I am trying to do is have a asp repeater that dynamically generates a given number of connected jQuery sortable list groups. Then I want to save the order of each of these list groups to a MS SQL Database, once the user presses an asp button.

The initial population of list items to the unordered sortable lists works fine and the ability to sort each list works fine.

A sample of the code is below. I've changed variable/method names, omitted code I felt weren't necessary to the issue.

**HTML/ASP:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="MyRepeater_ItemDataBound">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="col-md-6">
              <strong>Column 1</strong>
              <br />
              <ul id="Sortable1" class="sortable" runat="server"></ul>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
              <strong>Column 2</strong>
              <br />
              <ul id="Sortable2" class="sortable" runat="server"></ul>
         </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SaveButton" Text="Save Layout" OnClick="SaveButton_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**C# Code Behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {
          List<MyObject> myObjects = GetMyObjectsFromDB();
          MyRepeater.DataSource = myObjects;
          MyRepeater.DataBind();
     }
}

protected void MyRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
         HtmlGenericControl ul1 = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("Sortable1");
         HtmlGenericControl ul2 = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("Sortable2");

         // script block that'll be added to every group of sortable lists to allow for the connected sorting functionality
         string scriptBlock =
             @"<script type=""text/javascript"">
                  $(function () {
                       $(""#" + ul1.ClientID + @""").sortable({
                            connectWith: ""#" +  ul2.ClientID + @"""
                       }).disableSelection();
                  });

                  $(function () {
                       $(""#" + ul2.ClientID + @""").sortable({
                           connectWith: ""#" + ul1.ClientID + @"""
                       }).disableSelection();
                  });
             </script>";

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), ul1.ClientID + ul2.ClientID, scriptBlock);

        List<MyOtherObject> myObjectsForEachListGroup = GetMyListObjectsFromDB((int)DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "GroupId"));

        AddListItemsToSortables(ul1, ul2, myObjectsForEachListGroup);
    }

}

private void AddListItemsToSortables(HtmlGenericControl ul1, HtmlGenericControl ul2, List<MyOtherObject> myObjectsForEachListGroup)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myObjectsForEachListGroup.Count; i++)
    {
         HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
         li.Attributes.Add("id", myObjectsForEachListGroup[i].Id.ToString());
         li.Attributes.Add("class", "ui-state-default");
         li.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
         li.InnerText = myObjectsForEachListGroup[i].Name;

         if (i % 2 == 0)
         {
             ul1.Controls.Add(li);
         }
         else
         {
             ul2.Controls.Add(li);
         }
     }
}


private void SaveOrder()
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem rptItem in MyRepeater.Items)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl ul1 = (HtmlGenericControl)rptItem.FindControl("Sortable1");
        HtmlGenericControl ul2 = (HtmlGenericControl)rptItem.FindControl("Sortable2");

        int i = 0;

        foreach (HtmlGenericControl li in ul1.Controls)
        {
            // save the row and column for the given object in the DB
            UpdateMyObjectPosition(Convert.ToInt32(li.ClientID), i, 0);
            i++;
        }

        i = 0;

        foreach (HtmlGenericControl li in ul2.Controls)
        {
            // save the row and column for the given object in the DB
            UpdateMyObjectPosition(Convert.ToInt32(li.ClientID), i, 1);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that each `<li>` element won't persist during the postback. The `ul1.Controls` and `ul2.Controls` just contains a `LiteralControl` in my `SaveLayout` method and nothing else. I tried removing the `!Page.IsPostBack` from the `Page_Load` method and it just reinitializes the repeater lists during postback and doesn't give me the changed order.

I tried looking into a couple stackoverflow questions about having persisting dynamic control data by storing the ID's of the controls in a view state but it doesn't seem to work in my case. Or maybe I didn't do it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my issue by using javascript and a asp HiddenField which will get the order of the lists:

```
function GetOrder() {
    var order1 = $("#<%= Sortable1.ClientID %>").sortable('toArray').toString();
    var order2 = $("#<%= Sortable2.ClientID %>").sortable('toArray').toString();

    document.getElementById("<%= DynamicFieldData.ClientID %>").value = order1 + " " + order2;
}
```

The button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SaveButton" Text="Save Layout" OnClick="SaveButton_Click" OnClientClick="GetOrder()" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
```

Where `DynamicFieldData` is the HiddenField where you'll store the array of ID's of each item in the list. Then you can pull the value in the HiddenField in your code-behind and make use of it how you want.

I also had to modify my SaveOrder() method in my code-behind to now loop through the strings (that I split up) in the HiddenField value.